# ProgressBar disappears before the pdf load

Tags: android

I am using the `com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2` library for rendering the pdf from stream. For the small size pdf files the progress bar is working fine. Showing while loading and become invisible  when loading completes. But when it loads large size pdf files. The ProgressBar runs for some time and disappear before the pdf appear on screen. How to make the ProgressBar to show until the pdf appear on screen. Also is there any ways to get the loading values for making the ProgressBar deterministic. My code is given below

```
class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String,Void,InputStream>{


    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream((urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return inputStream;

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {


        pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).swipeHorizontal(false).load();
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your missing some listeners to help you with. Please check below code may help.

```
class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String,Void,InputStream>implements OnLoadCompleteListener{


@Override
protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {

            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream((urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return inputStream;

}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {


    pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).swipeHorizontal(false).onLoad(this).load();
   // mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}



  @Override
public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
  mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

}
```